# Where to find rejected tag edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I got `Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.` when I try to add a new tag wiki today,

So where can I find about the rejected ones ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see them on your [activity page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11318/warl0ck?tab=activity&sort=suggestions):

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/3947
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/3960
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/3959
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/3997
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/3996

This is the same thing that happened to [another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits); you can't plagiarize Wikipedia articles, they have attribution requirements. I think it's technically legal to do it if you link to the Wikipedia page as well, but we'd rather people just write new tag wikis. The tag wiki should describe when the tag should be used, not just what the term means

Comment: you're right, I shouldn't be copying them from wiki directly

Comment: Maybe there could be some warning placed on the tag wiki suggest page